# How to fix HTML source code from simply "return View" in controller in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I found that basic login function (Account controller) has something wrong - When I can login successfully, no problems. But, in case, password is wrong, etc, it goes through the logic, and goes to default :, and return View (model) to go back to Login screen as below.

When you login, it shows regular basic login screen with e-mail and password, and I entered the e.g. wrong password.

Then, View (model) from controller returns HTML source code that I don't want to, but I need to have regular screen that user can continue to fix the login. Would you please give me an advice about how to fix this issue?

(returned path : `https://localhost:44337/Account/Login`) But, source code, not screen image, even after refreshing the screen. Help!

```
// This doesn't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
// To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
       //return View("Login");
        return View(model);  // <<<=== Here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly reference the SignIn view with a line like...

```
return View("Login", model);
```

This will return the corresponding SignIn view with your model including existing data and ModelState.

Comment: Hi, I  just tried, but still same issue happened. Returned the HTML source code. This Account controller is basically from Microsoft (standard), and once I implemented Owin functions, it started to happen.... :-(     Those are namespaces ....          using System.Globalization;
using IdentitySample.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;